# How to interpret atop Disk usage and what disk usage is reasonable

Tags: linux, performance

I have a a couple of virtual machines all with the same provider. I'm using them for web hosting and have started to get intermittent slow page load times. I've installed atop to try and get to the bottom of the problem, but I'm don't know how to interpret the results.

Atop gives percentages for resource usage, but the man page suggests that those percentages are subjective:

> A critical occupation percentage means that is likely that this load causes a noticable negative
>          performance influence for applications using this resource.

My problem is that I don't know if I'm making undue demands of the system or whether there is a storage infrastructure problem with the host. The lines from atop when disk usage is high are:

```
LVM | roup-lv_root | busy     99% |  read     215 | write    302 | KiB/r     23 | KiB/w      4 | MBr/s   0.50  | MBw/s   0.12 | avio 19.1 ms |
DSK |          sda | busy     99% |  read     133 | write     78 | KiB/r     35 | KiB/w     13 | MBr/s   0.46  | MBw/s   0.10 | avio 46.7 ms |
```

Do these numbers represent an unreasonably high usage of resources?

Thanks